# Curry all swift function parameters, but don't call the function

Tags: swift, currying

I have the following swift function:

```
func foo(bar: String)(_ baz: String) {
  NSLog("bar \(bar), baz: \(baz)")
}

let f = foo("fizz")("buzz") // won't compile, foo returns Void
```

I want to pass that to `dispatch_async`, but I can't because I can't curry both parameters without invoking the function. How do I curry both `bar` and `baz` without calling the `foo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are free to change the function declaration, [Heath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29398264/9636) is correct. If you don't want to do that, then you just need to use an inline closure, e.g.

```
// pre-existing foo definition
func foo(bar: String)(_ baz: String) {
    NSLog("bar \(bar), baz: \(baz)")
}

let f = { foo("fizz")("buzz") }
f()
```

If your problem is you want to evaluate the arguments immediately, you can use a capture list:

```
let f = { [a=bar(),b=baz()] in foo(a)(b) }
```

Or when written as a call to `dispatch_async`:

```
dispatch_async(queue) { [a=bar(),b=baz()] in
    foo(a)(b)
}
```

This works because the capture list is evaluated immediately by the caller when the closure is created (as opposed to being evaluated when the closure is invoked).

Another option is to define a nested curried function. Nested functions are really just sugar for closures, but they can be more convenient:

```
/// Function that your code is executing in
func myFunc() {
    // ...

    // define a nested function
    func f(bar: String, baz: String)() {
        foo(bar)(baz)
    }

    // now call it
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), f("foo", "bar"))
}
```

---

Addendum: I strongly recommend against saying `NSLog("bar \(bar), baz: \(baz)")`. `NSLog` takes a format string and arguments, and so if either `bar` or `baz` contain anything that looks like a format token (e.g. `%@` or `%d`) then the call to `NSLog()` will behave badly and possibly crash. You have two reasonable options:

1. Say `NSLog("%@", "bar \(bar), baz: \(baz)")`
2. Say `NSLog("bar %@, baz: %@", bar, baz)`

The best option depends on whether your arguments are already compatible with `CVarArg` (which `String` is but e.g. `String?` is not). Also note that if your arguments are guaranteed to not contain format tokens, such as if they're numbers or booleans, then you can go ahead and use your existing `NSLog("bar \(someIntVar) baz \(someBoolVar)")` style.

Answer (score 3):

[Append an extra set of parens at the end of the function declaration](http://blog.xebia.com/2014/11/06/swift-function-currying/):

```
func foo(bar: String)(baz: String)() {
  NSLog("bar \(bar), baz: \(baz)")
}

let f = foo("fizz")("buzz") // compiles!
f() // logs: "bar fizz, baz: buzz"
```